# How do I save and edit a .py file in Github

Tags: python, github, spyder

I have a .py file saved on my desktop. How do I upload this on Github and also ensure that changes I make to this file on Spyder are saved on Github too?

Please can you answer step by step if possible?

Comment: " I have spent hours googling this and almost every answer assumes I know what "commit" means" Yes, understanding this sort of thing is a prerequisite. Github is a tool designed to give you a common point on the Internet to store your Git repository. This is only useful if you understand what a Git repository is, along with the basics of using one. This is a useful skill that you should learn. Given that you are already using Github, arguably the best place to learn these basics is through the [tutorials on the Github website](https://guides.github.com/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Place or replace your file in directory witch you got from github.
2. Open whole directory in VScode
3. In terminal type:

   - git add *
   - git commit -m "YOUR COMMENT"
   - git pull origin master
   - git push origin master

PS. - Don't forget to download git.

PSS. - I also recommend use TortoiseGit because it is easier (just right click on file and commit)